# TimeoutException: Message: timeout and webpages not loading/responding with ChromeDriver Chrome through Python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I run the code below I can't seem to get it to run threw without getting some sort of time out error or it seems to hang forever. Individually I can get them to work most times but only the CSI site seems to work consistently. Are their any changes I could make to have the script work not only better but simpler? Am I missing something? I'm new to Python and could use some help cleaning this up.

Thank you

```
import csv, os, time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from selenium import webdriver
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv, set_option
from matplotlib import pyplot
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from collections import Counter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook #Timer count
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from googlesearch import search

chrome_options      = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


start = time.time()
sleep_time          = 15

url_csi                 = 'http://www.csidata.com/factsheets.php?type=stock&format=html'
url_tmx                 = 'https://api.tmxmoney.com/en/migreport/search'
url_nyse                = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx'

database_csi            = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\CSI Historical Stock List\\"
database_tmx            = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\TMX Historical Stock List\\"
database_nyse           = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\NYSE Historical Stock List\\"
database_nasdaq         = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\NASDAQ Historical Stock List\\"
database_amex           = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\AMEX Historical Stock List\\"

master_file_csi         = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\CSI Historical Stock List\\CSI_Ticker_List_Historical.csv"
master_file_tmx         = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\TMX Historical Stock List\\TMX_Ticker_List_Historical.xlsx"
master_file_nyse        = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\NYSE Historical Stock List\\NYSE_Ticker_List_Historical.csv"
master_file_nasdaq      = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\NASDAQ Historical Stock List\\NASDAQ_Ticker_List_Historical.csv"
master_file_amex        = "E:\\Stock Database\\Historical Data\\Historical Stock List\\AMEX Historical Stock List\\AMEX_Ticker_List_Historical.csv"


#CSI Exchange Data Scraping

chrome_options      = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs               = {'download.default_directory': database_csi}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(name='prefs', value= prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
chrome_driver              = webdriver.Chrome(r"E:\Python Programs\chromedriver", chrome_options = chrome_options)

if os.path.exists(master_file_csi): os.remove(master_file_csi)
#Website
chrome_driver.get(url_csi)
#Navigate Web Page
chrome_driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > a:nth-child(3)').click()

time.sleep(sleep_time)

chrome_driver.close()

os.rename("%s"%database_csi+"stockfactsheet.csv","%s"%(master_file_csi))

#TMX Exchange Data Scraping
chrome_options      = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs               = {'download.default_directory': database_tmx}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(name='prefs', value= prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
chrome_driver              = webdriver.Chrome(r"E:\Python Programs\chromedriver", chrome_options = chrome_options)

if os.path.exists(master_file_tmx): os.remove(master_file_tmx)
#Website
chrome_driver.get(url_tmx)
#Navigate Web Page
time.sleep(sleep_time)
chrome_driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#leftside > div.idt_container > form > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(3)').click()
#leftside > div.idt_container > form > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(3)
#Download Data
time.sleep(sleep_time)
chrome_driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#leftside > div.idt_containerResults > div.searchToolBox > div.idtDownload > form > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(8)').click()

time.sleep(sleep_time)

chrome_driver.close()

os.rename("%s"%database_tmx+"mig_report.xlsx","%s"%(master_file_tmx))


#NYSE Exchange Data Scraping
chrome_options      = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs               = {'download.default_directory': database_nyse}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(name='prefs', value= prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
chrome_driver              = webdriver.Chrome(r"E:\Python Programs\chromedriver", chrome_options = chrome_options)

if os.path.exists(master_file_nyse): os.remove(master_file_nyse)
#Website
#Navigate Web Page
chrome_driver.get(url_nyse)
time.sleep(sleep_time)
chrome_driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#companyListDownloads > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > a').click()

time.sleep(sleep_time)

chrome_driver.close()

os.rename("%s"%database_nyse+"companylist.csv","%s"%(master_file_nyse))


#NASDAQ Exchange Data Scraping
chrome_options      = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs               = {'download.default_directory': database_nasdaq}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(name='prefs', value= prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
chrome_driver              = webdriver.Chrome(r"E:\Python Programs\chromedriver", chrome_options = chrome_options)

if os.path.exists(master_file_nasdaq): os.remove(master_file_nasdaq)
#Website
chrome_driver.get(url_nyse)
time.sleep(sleep_time)
#Navigate Web Page
chrome_driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#companyListDownloads > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a > div > svg').click()

time.sleep(sleep_time)

chrome_driver.close()

os.rename("%s"%database_nasdaq+"companylist.csv","%s"%(master_file_nasdaq))


#AMEX Exchange Data Scraping
chrome_options      = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs               = {'download.default_directory': database_amex}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option(name='prefs', value= prefs)
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
chrome_driver              = webdriver.Chrome(r"E:\Python Programs\chromedriver", chrome_options = chrome_options)

if os.path.exists(master_file_amex): os.remove(master_file_amex)
#Website
chrome_driver.get(url_nyse)
time.sleep(sleep_time)
#Navigate Web Page
chrome_driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#companyListDownloads > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a > div > svg').click()

time.sleep(sleep_time)

chrome_driver.close()

os.rename("%s"%database_amex+"companylist.csv","%s"%(master_file_amex))
```

Error

```
TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

After many attempts I found a solution. The issue looks to be when the page is trying to load. For some reason when I launch from chromedriver it take so long to load and this fix seems to have helped. It simply stops pictures to load.

```
 prefs = {'download.default_directory': database_csi,'profile.managed_default_content_settings.images': 2}
```

Comment: Can you add the error and where it happens in your code?

Comment: added an error message above. Now this example happened when getting the url_nyse but it doesn't always happen to that particular url it has also happened with url_tmx. NYSE, AMEX and NASDAQ all pull from the same url_nyse and will sometimes work and sometimes doesn't in not noticeable pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *can get them to work most times but only the CSI site seems to work consistently* count yourself lucky as this error message...

```
TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

...implies that the **WebDriver** instance *timesout* while trying to communicate with the **WebBrowsing** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.42*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

- You are using *chrome=71.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.45*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v70-72**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.42* and the *Chrome Browser v71.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.45**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v70-72*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: I did the chromedriver update. I'm getting timeout errors now when trying the url_nyse. The page pulls up yet it's still working and it won't move on. When I look up the url_nyse in my regular browser it pops up instantly and so is their potentially another reason why I cant get this script to collect the data from url_nyse?

Answer (score 0):

Its not uncommon for web pages to take a good long while to load while being driven by selenium/webdriver.
One quick solution would be to increase the amount of time the program waits while looking for an element.
The shortest way to get there is to simply increase the value of `sleep_time`. But this will increase the overall runtime of the script.

In my selenium scripts I like to use WebDriverWait by importing:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
SELENIUM_TIMEOUT = 10  # define a global timeout (in seconds)
```

Then when I go looking for an element on the page the code looks like.

```
try:
    element_is_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'myCustomElementID'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, SELENIUM_TIMEOUT).until(element_is_present)
    my_element = driver.find_element_by_id('myCustomElementID')
    my_element.click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("Handle the exception here")
```

This code will check for the presence of an element on the page that has the id=`myCustomElementID`

Once that condition is satisfied, the script will continue on.